# Show Text behind recycler view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to show a message when the filter of my recycler view has no items in the results. So i have a fixed text (in string.xml) hide by default behind recycler view and I want to show it when no result of filter but I cant show it, the code I used dont work.

I have the "hide" text in a LinearLayout (this is the view that I show/hide depends of filter results) in  app_bar_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutFilterNotFound"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:elevation="-100dp"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/gris"
            android:text=":(\nNo data"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

And the code I used to manage it is the following:

```
public void showNoFilterText() {
        if (!activar){
            View appbarMainScreen = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_bar_main, null);
            LinearLayout layoutToShow = appbarMainScreen.findViewById(R.id.layoutFilterNotFound);
            layoutToShow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try hiding recycler view and show text view

Answer (score 0):

I see you have this text in another layout. If this "Empty view" contains only text I think you can just add TextView to the layout where you have recycler view. Then you will have to just hide recycler if no items and show TextView.

If you want to have it in separate layout then you have to for example `include` it in layout with list (https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts). Rest with change visibility stays the same

Comment: The point is I want to show allways recyclerview on top, and only when recicler view has no items show the linearLayout (maybe layout have more view in a future) so i need has visible the Linear Layout and hide it again when reciclerview has items again but the atribute setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); dont work

Comment: But you need add this LinearLayout to layout with Recycler, for example using `include` tag in your xml (link in answer). The way you're doing it now will not work, because TextView is not a part of the current layout. If you do that you should be able to show/hide it as usual.

Comment: With inflating the view and the linear design instance it should work right? What would be the correct / professional way to display an alternative text in case of not having elements? Does the include be the most effective?

Comment: If you just inflate view like u did there it will not work, because this inflated view is not added to any parent. You could do something like `parent.add(inflatedView)` but for me, Im always adding empty view in XML file and show/hide it accordingly